# How do I fix a 504 gateway timeout error?

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-504

My web application (Django + Nginx) calls another url in the backend. As it takes time like 15-20 minutes to get whatever from the other site, I am running into the 504 Bad Gateway error. Before I encrypted my website, I added the following commands to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and it worked.

```
proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
proxy_send_timeout 1800;
proxy_read_timeout 1800;
```

But now my website is transferred from http to https. It does not work any longer. I googled but did not find a solution. Can anybody kindly help with this? Thanks.